# Get range (min - max) of values concatenated in a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

given the following table

```
+-----------------------------+
| id | type | price | item_id |
|-----------------------------|
| 1  | 1    | 20    | 22      |
|-----------------------------|
| 2  | 1    | 22    | 22      |
|-----------------------------|
| 3  | 2    | 19    | 22      |
|-----------------------------|
| 4  | 2    | 11    | 22      |
|-----------------------------|
| 5  | 1    | 08    | 22      |
|-----------------------------|
| 6  | 2    | 25    | 22      |
+-----------------------------+
```

I am trying to select the data to create a view as follows in a single row

```
+-------------------------------------+
| type1_range | type2_range | item_id |
|-------------------------------------|
| 08 - 22     | 11 - 25     | 22      |
+-------------------------------------+
```

type1_range and type2_range are the minimum and maximum price for each types.

I can get the data in couple of rows using

```
SELECT type, MAX (price) , MIN (price) 
FROM table 
where item_id=22 GROUP BY type;

+----------------------------+
| type | max | min | item_id |
|----------------------------|
| 1    | 22  | 08  | 22      |
|----------------------------|
| 2    | 25  | 11  | 22      |
+----------------------------+
```

But I am trying to concat the rows like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| type1_range | type2_range | item_id |
|-------------------------------------|
| 08 - 22     | 11 - 25     | 22      |
+-------------------------------------+
```

What would be sql required for this?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Please edit your database tag. And What happen if you have `type = 3, 4, 5, ...`? Do you only have 2 type values or unlimited type values?

Comment: only two types for now and using postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
      MIN(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN price END),
      ' - ',
      MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN price END)
    ) as type1range,
    CONCAT(
      MIN(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN price END),
      ' - ',
      MAX(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN price END)
    ) as type2range.
    item_id
FROM table
WHERE item_id = 22
GROUP BY item_id
```

You've tagged two different database systems (please avoid doing this) but I believe they do both support CONCAT() for string concatenation

If you want to omit the item_id from the select list (you already know it's item 22) you can remove the GROUP BY. Alternatively if you remove the WHERE and leave the group by you'll get a row for each item_id

To get more of an idea as to how it works, remove the concat and the min/max - you'll see that the case when causes the price to show up only if the type is 1 (in the type 1 range column) otherwise it's null. It's the. Trivial for the min and max to work on just type 1 or just type 2 data for each column. It's actually a form of pivot query if you want to read up on them more

Comment: This method is useless if there is multiple item_id's has to be given in a range

Comment: You're mistaken; this query functions identically to yours (now you've edited the inner join bug out of yours) but will always be more efficient because it only accesses and groups the table once- yours does that 3 times and then joins the results. I would point out that that I've answered the question being asked; you seem to be trying to imagine enhance requirements that haven't been asked and provide an answer to an unasked question?

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward approach would be having type1_range and type2_range as two sub-queries and join with the distinct id's like shown below,

```
SELECT t.item_id,type1_range,type2_range
FROM (Select distinct item_id from table) t 
LEFT join
(SELECT item_id,type, concat(MIN(price),'-' ,MAX(price) ) as type1_range
FROM table 
where type=1 
GROUP BY item_id,type)type1 on type1.item_id=t.item_id
LEFT join
(SELECT item_id,type, concat(MIN(price),'-' ,MAX(price) ) as type2_range
FROM table 
where type=2 
GROUP BY item_id,type)type2 on type2.item_id=t.item_id
```

Comment: This is rather complicated and resource intensive/wasteful. It also produces no result for type 1 if an item has no type 2 or vice versa

Comment: Thank you for the insight but why It also produces no result for type 1 if an item has no type 2 or vice versa?

Comment: If you look at your edit history you'll see your answer was INNER JOIN until I pointed this out..

Comment: I have edited 9 minutes ago and your comment is 6 minutes ago, that's why